# Remove exiftool traces from file

Tags: metadata, video-processing, exiftool

If I set some tag with exiftool e.g.

```
exiftool UserComment="test" video.mp4
```

I can then remove it with

```
exiftool UserComment= video.mp4
```

However, exiftool sets an additional tag `ExifToolVersion` which I cannot delete with

```
exiftool -ExifToolVersion= video.mp4
```

because

```
Warning: Sorry, ExifToolVersion is not writable
```

How can I remove all traces of exiftool from the file? I need to keep other meta data tags untouched.

Answer (score 5):

ExifToolVersion is not stored in the file.  This is only information returned by ExifTool.  Use the -G1 option to see the group name for each tag.  Tags with a group name of "ExifTool" are generated internally.  Other "ExifTool" tags are Error and Warning.  For a complete list, see the [Extra Tags documentation](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Extra.html)

Comment: You are right. But if you write a *.csv file with -g1 or -G1, the above information will be included like the FILE or SYSTEM informations. Is it possible to write only the included metadata to a *.csv?

Comment: @PeterCo (better late than never): Add these options to your command to extract only tags existing in the file: --system:all --exiftool:all -e